why do case insensitive and max length , cs50x 2024 speller problem
I am suck in this problem for 3 weeks and it blows my mind
problem in many cases , specially case insensitive
please help
in the functions of load or check or hash
and also problem with dealing with max length
i have changed some details in the dectionary.h file that i declared the node structure in the dictionary header file , to assure no conflict and when executing the code
./speller texts/lalaland.txt
terminated

#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


#ifndef NODEHASH
#define NODEHASH 1
#endif

#ifndef FASTALLOC
#define FASTALLOC 1
#endif

#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table


// TODO: Choose number of buckets in hash table
#if 0
const unsigned int N = 187751;
#else
enum { N = 187751 };
#endif

// Hash table
node *table[N];

// word countting
int word_count = 0;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary, else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
    // TODO
    unsigned int h_val = hash(word);
    node *temp = table[h_val];
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        #if NODEHASH
        if (temp->hash != h_val)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
            continue;
        }
        #endif
        if (strcmp(temp->word, word) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return false;
}


// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
    unsigned int hash = 0;
    while (*word)
    {
        unsigned char c = toupper((unsigned char)*word); // تحويل الأحرف إلى حالة صغيرة
        hash += c;
        hash += (hash << 10);
        hash ^= (hash >> 6);
        word++;
    }
    hash += (hash << 3);
    hash ^= (hash >> 11);
    hash += (hash << 15);
    return hash % N;
}


// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful, else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
    FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }

    char word[LENGTH + 1];
    while (fgets(word, sizeof(word), file) != NULL)
    {
        word[strcspn(word, "\r\n")] = '\0';
        node *n = new_node();
        if (n == NULL)
        {
            fclose(file);
            return false;
        }
        strncpy(n->word, word, LENGTH);
        n->word[LENGTH] = '\0';
        unsigned int pos = hash(word);
        #if NODEHASH
        n->hash = pos;
        #endif
        n->next = table[pos];
        table[pos] = n;
        word_count++;
    }
    fclose(file);
    return true;
}

#if FASTALLOC
node *freelist = NULL;
int free_count = 0;
#define ARENASIZE 1000

node *new_node(void)
{
    node *index;
    while (1)
    {
        index = freelist;
        if (index != NULL)
        {
            freelist = index->next;
            break;
        }

        freelist = (node *) malloc(ARENASIZE * sizeof(node));
        if (freelist == NULL)
        {
            return NULL;
        }

        node *prv = NULL;
        for (index = freelist; index < &freelist[ARENASIZE]; ++index)
        {
            index->alloc = 0;
            index->next = prv;
            prv = index;
        }
        freelist->alloc = 1;
    }
    return index;
}
#endif

unsigned int size(void)
{
    return word_count;
}

bool unload(void)
{
    node *cur;
    node *next;


    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        cur = table[i];
        while (cur != NULL)
        {
            next = cur->next;
            free(cur);
            cur = next;
        }
        table[i] = NULL;
    }
    freelist = NULL;
    return true;
}


You note that you have changed some details in the header file along with relocating the node structure, but you do not include the text for that header file in your issue.  Without that, there is no way to compile at least a minimal example.  Please include the missing information so that others can compile your code.
